# Using openAm as an IDP and another service provider throws Exception with Name ID Format

Tags: single-sign-on, openam

I am trying to configure SSO for my application using OpenAm as IDP and application itself as service provider.

Folowing is the metadata of the IDP and Service Provider:

```
  <EntityDescriptor entityID="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
<IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <ArtifactResolutionService index="0" isDefault="true" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/ArtifactResolver/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/IDPSloRedirect/metaAlias/idp" ResponseLocation="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/IDPSloRedirect/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/IDPSloPOST/metaAlias/idp" ResponseLocation="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/IDPSloPOST/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/IDPSloSoap/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/IDPMniRedirect/metaAlias/idp" ResponseLocation="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/IDPMniRedirect/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/IDPMniPOST/metaAlias/idp" ResponseLocation="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/IDPMniPOST/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/IDPMniSoap/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</NameIDFormat>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:WindowsDomainQualifiedName</NameIDFormat>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:kerberos</NameIDFormat>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName</NameIDFormat>
    <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/SSORedirect/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/SSOPOST/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/SSOSoap/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <NameIDMappingService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/NIMSoap/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <AssertionIDRequestService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/AIDReqSoap/IDPRole/metaAlias/idp"/>
    <AssertionIDRequestService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:URI" Location="http://www.cpfdomain.com:8091/openam_10.0.1/AIDReqUri/IDPRole/metaAlias/idp"/>
</IDPSSODescriptor>
```

Service Provider Metadata:

```
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="test">
    <SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <KeyDescriptor>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <X509Data>
                    <X509Certificate>Key Info</X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </KeyDescriptor>
        <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="LOGOUT LOCATION URI" ResponseLocation="LOGOUT LOCATION URI"/>
        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
        </NameIDFormat>
        <AssertionConsumerService index="0" isDefault="true" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="ASSERTION URI"/>
    </SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

When I test the federation, I always get the following error:

```
message Error processing AuthnRequest. Service provider does not support name identifier format urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient.
```

I have removed this identifier from both IDP and SP in the circle of trust I am testing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you have removed NameIdFormat 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient' from both IdP and SP MetaData you can not use it ... this should be obvious.

Of course you have to test SSO by specifying a NameIdFormat which both entities support ... in your case 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress'.

To test IdP-initiated SSO with HTTP-POST Binding use ...

OPENAM_SCHEME://OPENAM_FQDN:OPENAM_PORT/OPENAM_DEPLOYMENT_URI/idpssoinit?NameIDFormat=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress&metaAlias=IDP_META_ALIAS&spEntityID=test&binding=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST

Comment: Thanks for your response.. My issue has been fixed.. I just deleted the IDP and SP and created a new circle of trust with new IDP and SP, registered the metadata on both the sides.. What I missed was to specify the **Signing Key Info** while creating the IDP..

Comment: Well if that was your only problem (which I doubt), then you could have provide the certificate alias under the AssertionContent tab of the entity's configuration and then just export/import the new metadata on the remote instance (so it knows about the certificate as well).